# UIImage to NSURL

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have generated an image in my app an I would like to share it via UIDocumentInteractionController which takes an argument in form of NSURL. Of course I don't want do directly convert image data into a URL, but what is the best way to achieve this? Can you temporarily store that image somewhere and then get the url and delete it afterwards after UIDocumentInteractionController has done it's job? Or convert it to NSData somehow and then get the url of the NSData object? (I tried this and failed btw)

Comment: Perhaps you should use `UIActivityViewController` and pass the `UIImage` as the activity item.

Comment: I am using that already but i need UIDocumentInteractionController aswell because it can send the image to more apps.

Comment: Then you have no choice but to write the `UIImage` to a temporary file.